Why my PowerShell Remoting Commands/Traffic are being Routed to Event Server instead of going to Actual Machine?
I am in a domain network, just a few days ago PowerShell worked fine, but now it's failing. After Examining the issue, I found that the port 5985 traffic is being Routed to Event Server, Instead of going directly to intended machine. Can anybody tell me why it's happening, and how do I fix this.(Thanks)
I tried to create PowerShell Session from one machine to another, but it failed because the 5985 port traffic is being Routed to Event Server in my domain and the firewall is blocking the traffic, While a few days ago this traffic went directly to intended machine and Everything was Cool.

Port number 5985 is reserved for Windows PowerShell Default psSession Port Windows Remote Management Service (WinRM-HTTP).  It is possible the Gateway that is being used for 5985 is not working properly.  IP routing can use two different methods 1) Routing by IP address and mask 2) Getting route from a Gateway.  if you are failing I suspect that DHCP is enabled and you are not getting the route to the remote machine.  I would try from cmd.exe > IPConfig/renew  DHCP periodically assign a new IP address to a machine.  It may be an issue with the new address that is causing the issue.

Try PING the remote machine by IP and by NAME and see if you have a route to the machine

It appears to me that your network admins made a change that directs traffic on port 5985 to a specific machine/IP address. You should talk to them and confirm whether or not this is the case.

This isn't really a programming question or a problem with PowerShell itself. Something external to PowerShell seems to be re-routing your traffic to an unintended endpoint. This is most likely going to be a networking-based problem and solution.

(Reply to: codewario). Exactly, that's what I think, as it's a domain network, it has all the serversI mean separate server for each role link ca, DC, dhcp, event, etc. and an a firewall between servers and clients, also a group policy is there, but the issue is I analyzed everything I could guess.but the main reason of why the traffic is being directed to server side instead of just it's destination. Current route it's taking is request is generated and it travels to event server, then it moves toward destination machine. Firewall allows inbound traffic to servers.

But block outbound so the request is blocked in middle.Can I make the request instead of heading to server side just ho toward target machine.(THANKS FOR REPLY!)
